# Mod-Rewrite uses escaped string in substitution

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, vhosts

Following situation:

Source URL is in the format: 
`https://example.com/tmp/x%23.jpg`

The target file is located on the filesystem under the following path (relative to document root): `var/assets/tmp/x#.jpg`

So I'd like to rewrite this path to the local file using the following rule:
`RewriteRule "^tmp/x#.jpg$" /var/assets/$0 [PT,L]`

I've also tried the following approach:
`RewriteRule "^tmp/x#.jpg$" /var/assets/%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]`

But they all result in a 404, with the following message:
`The requested URL /var/assets/tmp/x was not found on this server.` 
The interesting thing is that the URL is cut off after the `x`, so where the first special character is.

Another interesting fact is that the following condition matches, but the rule fails:

`RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/var/assets%{REQUEST_URI} -f # matches
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/assets%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L] # file not found`

Maybe some has an idea how i can solve this problem.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `#` is a url fregment and its not sent the server.You will need javasccript or other client side logic to handle  this.

Comment: It is sent to the server when encoded like this: `https://example.com/tmp/x%23.jpg`  and the rule `RewriteRule "^tmp/x#.jpg$"`matches as  well, but in the substitution the backreference or `%{REQUEST_URI}` contain `tmp/x%23.jpg` instead of the decoded value `tmp/x#.jpg`